# SQLite where clause Issue

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I have around `30` records into SQLite table, where `10` records belongs to source from **Online** and rest `20` records belongs to source from **Offline**.

Now, I want to get all the `records` that belongs to **source** from `Online`, for that I wrote this:

```
String sQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REMINDERS + " where " + KEY_SOURCE + " = 'Online'";
```

But by using above query, I am *getting all the records* available in database, no matter from where it belongs to Offline or Online

So where I have mistaken, why I am not able to get data that belongs to source '`Online`' only

**Whereas**, I have used below query to `delete data` from table that belongs to `source 'Online'` and it works for me:

```
db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_REMINDERS + " where " + KEY_SOURCE + " = 'Online'");
```

**Code**

```
public List<Reminder> getAllOnlineReminders(){

        // String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REMINDERS + " where " + KEY_SOURCE + " = 'Online'";

        String[] args = new String[]{"Online"};

        List<Reminder> reminderList = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REMINDERS + " WHERE " + KEY_SOURCE + "=?", args);

        // Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // Looping through all rows and adding to list
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Reminder reminder = new Reminder();
                reminder.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                reminder.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                reminder.setmSource(cursor.getString(2));

                // Adding Reminders to list
                reminderList.add(reminder);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return reminderList;
    }
```

But still getting all the records, whereas I just want to get records that belongs to source 'Online'

Comment: have you checked your database records. I suspect that all records are having Online as source

Comment: Post your Table Structure.

Comment: Is there duplicate entries?

Comment: can you post the codes of how you use sQuery as well?

Comment: @AngelKoh I posted code, please check now

Comment: @VivekMishra no I checked several times I have many records that belongs to Online and Offline both into my database

Comment: Your commented `selectQuery` string doesn't work as well?

Comment: @Sun, you can try my codes. it's what I am using currently. hope it helps.

Comment: thank you guys, I found the mistake, now I got the solution, I was using getAllReminders() instead of getAllOnlineReminders() in onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
String[] args = new String[]{"Online"};
// For select
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REMINDERS + " WHERE " + KEY_SOURCE + "=?", args);

// For delete
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_REMINDERS + " WHERE " + KEY_SOURCE + "=?", args);
```

Comment: thank you, I found the mistake, now I got the solution, I was using getAllReminders() instead of getAllOnlineReminders() in onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try this. It's adapted from my own sqlite codes. Hope it helps.

```
    private final String[] allColumns = {"id", "title", KEY_SOURCE}; 
     //or whatever your column name is

    String[] args = {"Online"};

    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(TABLE_REMINDERS, // a. table
                    allColumns, // b. column names
                    KEY_SOURCE + "=?", // c. selection
                    args, // d. selections args
                    null, // e. group by
                    null, // f. having
                    null, // g. order by
                    null); // h. limit
```

**IMPORTANT:** not related to your question, but do remember to call cursor.close(); after you have finished using it.

Answer (score -1):

Cursor findEntry = db.query("sku_table", columns, "owner=?", new String[] { owner }, null, null, null);

Comment: Cursor findEntry = db.query("TABLE_REMINDERS ", columns, "Online=?", new String[] { Online}, null, null, null);

Comment: and... **why**? `rawQueries` work just as fine as `query()`